# Turning Raw data into TypeORM Entity

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have data that I am sending to my NodeJs server that is in the standard SQL format with the default SQL column names etc.

I want to take these raw entities and reinsert them into the db. It seems like I can't insert them straight up without converting them into entities, or preparing a raw SQL statement.

I want to turn these values into TypeORM entities automatically without having to write transform functions.

Is there a good way to accomplish this in TypeORM?

Comment: We can assume that my entities are not in the db yet, but that I have raw table row values in SQL

Comment: What format is your data in? I don't believe "the standard SQL format" you mention is any standard at all. Show what your data looks like, and what you entity looks like, and maybe then we can help you here.

Comment: So for TypeORM you map your column names in the database to your property names in your entity, right? The data I am getting is just raw row data from the db. TypeORM must use internal functions already to map the db column names to the properties. I want to be able to do that on the fly.

I.E 
db row data:
id:
customer_name:
order_number:

To entity:
id: 
customerName: 
orderNumber:

The naming scheme doesn't have to be that obvious though of snake to camel. In TypeORM you could have the property name unrelated to the db column name if you wanted @AlexWayne

Comment: RawSqlResultsToEntityTransformer looks relevant